# SQLite update issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with update query in sqlite [ android ]

here is an update method:

```
public int Updater(String pass, String na, String sur, String cou,String log){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colPassword, pass);
    cv.put(colName, na);
    cv.put(colSurn, sur);
    cv.put(colCountry, cou);
    return sqLiteDatabase.update(Usr_TABLE, cv, colLogin+"="+log, new String []{colLogin});   
}
```

I'm receiving error:

```
Error updating Name=qwewqeq Login=tesg Surname=gfgfg Country=ewrwe Password=dfsdfds using UPDATE USERS SET Name=?, Login=?, Surname=?, Country=?, Password=? WHERE Login=bla
```

and later

Finalizing a cursor that has not been deactivated or closed

BUT

I have closed everything

here is calling of update:

```
public void FinishCl(View v){
    sql = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    editps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pasek);
    edytn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wyname);
    editsn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wysurname);
    editctry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wycountry);
    psw = editps.getText().toString();
    nr= edytn.getText().toString();
    srn = editsn.getText().toString();
    ctr= editctry.getText().toString();
    sql.openToWrite();
    sql.Updater(psw, nr, srn, ctr,"iie");
    sql.close();
    startActivity(new Intent(this,UserPanel.class));
}
```

check login method is closing as well:

```
public void OkCl(View v){
    enterLog = enterLogin.getText().toString();
    enterPass = enterPassword.getText().toString();
    sqa=  new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    sqa.openToRead();
    Log.i("login",enterLog);
    Log.i("password",Login.enterPass);
    if(sqa.logineSelector(enterLog, enterPass)==true){
        Log.i("zwrocilo", "true");
        startActivity(new Intent(this,UserPanel.class));
       sqa.close();
    }
    else if (sqa.logineSelector(enterLog, enterPass)==false){
        sqa.close();
        Log.i("zwrocilo", "false");
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox.setMessage("Wrong password or login");
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            }
        });
        alertbox.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `colLogin` is the name of the column and `log` is it's value, your parameters `whereClause` and `whereArgs` seem to be messed up.

I believe it should be

```
return sqLiteDatabase.update(Usr_TABLE, cv, colLogin+"=?", new String []{log});
```

or

```
return sqLiteDatabase.update(Usr_TABLE, cv, colLogin+"="+log, null);
```

since `whereArgs` are replacement for "?" in your `whereClause`.

Comment: now I'm getting error: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg =no such column login_name

Comment: `colLogin` should store actual name of the column

Comment: static final String colLogin="Login" - it does. Did u mean this?

Comment: it's strange then. do both my suggestions result in that error?

Comment: the result tis the same, error: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg =no such column login_name, could you explain to me why in sqlite we do not use the pure sql queries? Is is banned?

Comment: if it's your database - you can use rawQuery() method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html